# How to do superscripts in referencing for LateX

Tags: cross-referencing, superscripts

The article is some kind of like this:

[image]

```
@article{schripsema2019similarity,
  title={Similarity and differential NMR spectroscopy in metabolomics: application to the analysis of vegetable oils with 1 H and 13 C NMR},
  author={Schripsema, Jan},
  journal={Metabolomics},
  volume={15},
  number={3},
  pages={39},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

I had tried:

```
  title={Similarity and differential NMR spectroscopy in metabolomics: application to the analysis of vegetable oils with ^{1}H and ^{13}C NMR},
```

But the outcome is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are packages for writing chemical formulas, but if you just need to raise that text you can do like this:

```
... vegetable oils with \textsuperscript{1}H and \textsuperscript{13}C NMR},
```

which with

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sup.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{schripsema2019similarity}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a ghost space to raise, or lower, a position holder. For example `${}^{13}F_{2}$`. Another is `${}_{x}^{y}F_{u}^{v}$`.